# Ndarray to list in python not working?

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I have the following code in my program that's giving me grief:

```
def binfunctionII(stuff, binwidth):
    B = stuff[:,4]
    bins=np.linspace(min(B), max(B)+binwidth, 
                            ((max(B)+binwidth)-min(B))/binwidth)
    out = []
    for i in range(len(bins)-1):
        temp=(B>=bins[i])&(B<bins[i+1])
        out.append(stuff[temp])
    return out

for t in range(len(alldata)):
    certaindata = alldata[t]
    print t
    Vdata = certaindata[np.argsort(certaindata[:, 4])]
    print Vdata
    Vdatavals = list(binfunctionII(Vdata, 1))
```

(That is currently the only way i know how to bin by width and not size of bin. I tried using `out = list()` instead of `out = []` but it didn't change anything, the dtype's and size's remained.)

It is currently an ndarray, giving me stuff like below (which is what it should) but i need to be able to iterate over the stuff later, and right now it's a mess.

```
[array([[  12.11974609,   13.4       ,   63.4       ,    4.1       ,
     129.98302733,   37.30872341]]), 
 array([], shape=(0L, 6L), dtype=float64), 
 array([], shape=(0L, 6L), dtype=float64), 
 array([], shape=(0L, 6L), dtype=float64), 
 array([[  13.78698792,   16.12224827,   59.        ,    4.1       ,
     174.01460895,   44.40542507]]),...]
```

I want just:

```
[[12.11974609, 13.4, 63.4, 4.1, 129.98302733, 37.30872341],
 [13.78698792, 16.12224827, 59., 4.1, 174.01460895, 44.40542507],...]
```

**So i need:**

- All empty arrays taken out
- It made into a list that i can more easily work with
- Keeping in mind that some of the arrays (which are bins) have not 1 or 0 6-column rows, but maybe 3 or 4.

**I have tried** making it a list using `.tolist()`...

```
Vdatavals = np.ndarray(binfunctionII(Vdata, 1)).tolist()

    ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32
```

**I have also tried** instead of battling the ndarray-ness, just the empty arrays by doing

```
VdatavalsNONZERO = [x for x in Vdatavals if x != []]

    #But this literally changes nothing
```

**I have also tried** using `filter(None, sequence)`

```
VdatavalsNONZERO = filter(None, Vdata)

    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
    Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I do not know if it is my binning function `out` that needs to be changed, or if i can deal with the ndarray outside of the function. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.digitize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) seems like it could help you out here. By using this, you could build your list by, for example

```
def binfunctionII(stuff, binwidth):
    B = stuff[:,4]
    bins=np.linspace(min(B), max(B)+binwidth, 
                        ((max(B)+binwidth)-min(B))/binwidth)
    indices = np.digitize(B,bins)
    out = []
    for i in np.arange(np.max(indices)):
        out.append(list(B[indices==i]))
    return out
```

Comment: Whoa. So that did stuff at least! The only issues is it 1) added an empty `[ ]` before my first/0th arrays, it 2) cut off my very last arrays, it 3) erased all the other columns in each array and only retained the 4th column, and it 4) didn't get rid of the empty arrays but i think i can fix that. So to illustrate, it went from me needing `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[],[], [], [2,2,2,2,2,2], [], [], [], [], [3,3,3,3,3,3], [], [4,4,4,4,4,4]]` to be  `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4,4,4]]` but it gave me `[[1],[],[], [], [2], [], [], [], [], [3], []]` does that make sense?

Comment: Also, if there are two or more values in a bin, i lose information about the other columns, and each `[]` now will have something like `[2,3]` which would be the 4th column values from two different rows, but i need it to remain like `[[2,2,2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3,3,3]]`